# How can I stop Visual Studio 2010 from highlighting paragraphs?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have to manually edit a bunch of HTML and ASP.NET pages that contain primarily content in `<p>` tags. In VS2010, when I open such a page in the designer it insists on highilighting all the paragraphs; surrounding them with dotted blue rectangles and shading all other paragraphs.

I find this annoying, can I turn these behaviours off?

---

EDIT

I managed to change the colours by going to Tools, Options, HTML Designer, View and editing the colours for "Layout UI activated border" and "Style application overlay".

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the colours for Brace Matching (full and outline) in Tools | Options | Environment | FOnts and Colors.

To disable delimiter highlighting: untick in Tools | Options | Text Editor | General (I don't think this can be set on a per-language basis, so it's all or nothing).

Comment: I think that's more for the text editor (or I couln't get it to work). It's the HTML/ASP.NET designer part where I'm having trouble.